# How do you execute multiple operations on a property using the Query Builder API?

Tags: java, servlets, xpath, aem, query-builder

In AEM 6.2 I created a Java servlet where I use QueryBuilder to query the JCR for relevant content.

I'm want to limit the search results to nodes that do not have the 'sling:resourceType' property or, if they do have it, it cannot be equal to 'social/qna/components/hbs/post'. Writing the XPATH query out like this works

`//*[jcr:contains(., 'searchTerm') and ((not (@sling:resourceType)) or (@sling:resourceType != 'social/qna/components/hbs/post')) and ((@jcr:primaryType = 'cq:Page') or (@jcr:primaryType = 'social:asiResource'))]`

But I can't figure out how to use the QueryBuilder API to create this query. This is what my QueryBuilder code looks like.

```
group.p.or=true
group.1_path=/content/myproject
group.2_path=/content/usergenerated/asi/jcr/content/myproject
1_group.p.or=true
1_group.1_type=cq:Page
1_group.2_type=social:asiResource
fulltext=searchTerm

property.p.or=true
property=sling:resourceType
property.operation=exists
property.value=false
property.1_operation=unequals
property.1_value=social/qna/components/hbs/post
```

How can I rewrite the property section so it only returns results where sling:resourceType property doesn't exist or does not equal 'social/qna/components/hbs/post'?

Comment: A suggestion, instead of using Querybuilder use SQL2, as implicitly the QB gets converted to XPATH and then gets converted to SQL2.
And with SQL2 its much easier to handle your use-case. `select * from [cq:Page]  where ([jcr:content/sling:resourceType] is null or [jcr:content/sling:resourceType] <> 'social/qna/components/hbs/post' ) and (ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/myproject') or ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/usergenerated/asi/jcr/content/myproject'))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been leaning toward going the SQL2 route, but I'm trying to select [cq:Page] as well as [social:asiResource] all in the same query. Is such a thing possible in SQL2?

Comment: try this - `select * from [nt:base] where ([jcr:primaryType] = 'cq:Page' || [jcr:primaryType] = 'social:asiResource'  ) and ([jcr:content/sling:resourceType] is null or [jcr:content/sling:resourceType] <> 'social/qna/components/hbs/post' ) and (ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/myproject') or ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/usergenerated/asi/jcr/content/myproject'))`

Comment: Whatever approach you take make sure to setup correct indexes so as to ensure optimum performance and avoid warnings in logs

Comment: Thank you for the help. I modified your query and it seems to be working with the exception of the CONTAINS I added. I will get the indexes set up, thanks for the heads up on that. Here's the modified query `SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE ([jcr:primaryType] = 'cq:Page' OR [jcr:primaryType] = 'social:asiResource') AND ([jcr:content/sling:resourceType] <> 'social/qna/components/hbs/post' OR [sling:resourceType] <> 'social/qna/components/hbs/post') AND (ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/myproject') OR ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/usergenerated/asi/jcr/content/myproject')) AND CONTAINS(*,'searchTerm')`